# Получить объекты между двумя точками Google Maps API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps-api, google-maps

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача получить города, находящиеся между точками `А` и `Б`, где точка `А` и точка `Б`, так же являются городами.

Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать сразу же несколько сервисов [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=ru)

1. [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start?hl=ru)
2. [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro?hl=ru)

В первый сервис отдаю данные:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=A&destination=B&mode=driving&key=API_KEY')
```

На выходе получаю очень много чего, но более всего, похоже, подходит `geocoded_waypoints`:

```
for i in r.json()['geocoded_waypoints']:
    print(i)
```

Получаю вывод такой:

```
{'geocoder_status': 'OK', 'place_id': 'ChIJ02oeW9PP20YR2XC13VO4YQs', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}
{'geocoder_status': 'OK', 'place_id': 'ChIJIdKiTjCGZ0ARZ6ku4alTMHo', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}
```

После чего, передаю `place_id` во второй сервис, для получения `latitude` и `longitude`

Но, проблема заключается в том, что между точкой `А` и `Б` находится намного больше `waypoints`

Как получить больше промежуточных объектов ?

Answer (score 1):

waypoints - это начало и конец. Directions API возвращает routes, у каждого route есть legs, у каждого leg есть steps. Не скажу сходу, в каком случае routes и legs м.б. > 1, в обычном случае нужно смотреть routes[0].legs[0].steps. У step есть end_location (place_id нет, к сожалению) - это координаты промежуточных объектов.

[image: Google Maps Directions API response sample]

Comment: Далее можно по координатам попытаться найти, что это за место такое. Но в случае type=driving, это будут перекрестки, съезды с трассы итп.